# Swift strange behavior - within function invocation and outside function invocation

Tags: swift

I tried to define a simple function within viewDidLoad like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // my method below
    func add(number1:Int, number2:Int)
    {
        println("sum \(number1 + number2)")
    }

    add(5, 7) // able to invoke simply by passing values
}
```

Here I was able to invoke add function simply by passing two integer values, but when I tried to define add method outside viewDidLoad like this:

```
// my method defined outside viewDidLoad
func add(number1:Int, number2:Int)
{
    println("sum \(number1 + number2)")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    add(5, number2: 7) // for second passed parameter I had to specify name of variable, since compiler was complaining
}
```

I was unable to invoke it simply by passing the two values, I had to specify name of second variable because compiler was complaining.

Any reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure why this error is occurring, I do know that specifying no label (e.g. `func add(_ number1:Int, _ number2:Int)` ) would allow for no label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David pointed out, functions used as methods (functions associated with an object, that is) handle parameters different to "plain" functions to enable ObjC-Style message passing:

> Specifically, Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local
>   parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent
>   parameter names both local and external parameter names by default.
>   This convention matches the typical naming and calling convention you
>   will be familiar with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for
>   expressive method calls without the need to qualify your parameter
>   names.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_300

In other words, Swift treats your function as if you had written it like this if it's defined as method:

```
func add(number1:Int, #number2:Int)
{
    println("sum \(number1 + number2)")
}
```

Adding the "#" to the second parameter in your first example makes the call work the same in both cases (function and method calling). The "#" itself is a shorthand for a parameter name that matches the local parameter name, so this would work, too:

```
func add(number1:Int, number2 number2:Int)
{
    println("sum \(number1 + number2)")
}
```

Which makes fixing the interface to make it callable in a more sentence-style way easy (while switching to swift-guide style brace placement):

```
func add(number1:Int, to number2:Int){
    println("sum \(number1 + number2)")
}

someInstance.add(2,to:3)
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

With Swift 3.0, this will change and all parameters have to be used when calling the function as declared. See:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md

Answer (score 0):

swift handles arguments to methods and functions differently.  With methods (for compatibility with Objective-C I suspect) only the initial tag: is omitted, the rest are required.  With functions, all of the tags are omitted.